# dirname(__FILE__) showing backslashes

Tags: php

I have a config file in my base directory and I'm trying to figure the absolute path to the directory to use for file includes. However windows is using backslashes in the path.

```
define( 'ABSOLUTE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));

include( ABSOLUTE_PATH . "/includes/include.php" );
```

Using this method it returns this path...

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\websites/includes/include.php
```

As you can see it is a mix of forward slashes and backslashes.

What is the best way for fixing this problem, or is there a better method that I can find the absolute path?

EDIT:

The reason I would like it to use a forward slash is I am serializing the results to be stored in a database. Backslashes are removed when serialized. :)

Comment: Why would you expect it *not* to include backslashes, since they are the correct path separator in a Windows environment?

Comment: Note that this mix is totally working for include, require and related function, I got something like this with such mix in a project but it works without any problem.

Comment: I do not believe it's a problem (Windows will use both), but you could try (the simplistic) `str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path)` to normalize.

Comment: PHP doesn't care what you use. It will work just fine with the mix (granted you could get cache misses). However, what you're looking for is path normalization/canonicalization. [`realpath`](http://php.net/realpath) will work, but it requires that the path exists; a user posted a solution at http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php#84012

Comment: Serialization should maintain the backslashes, otherwise you're serialization method is broken. If you're writing in the backslashes yourself, then you need to escape them, e.g. `'C:\\some\\path'`. My advice: use forward slashes and normalize the entire path as forward slashes; DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR is unnecessary: `echo file_get_contents('C:/xampp/readme_en.txt');` works just fine.

Answer (score 7):

You should be using the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant:

```
include( ABSOLUTE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "includes" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "include.php" );
```

Comment: This may very well be the best solution, but it diminishes readability significantly.  And it quickly gets worse with more folder nesting.  Try with: `"/includes/corp/finance/ca/include.php"`...  yikes!

Answer (score 1):

Using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is unnecessary in your example. As long as you use the forward slash, “/”, you’ll be OK. Windows doesn’t mind it, and it’s best for *nix operating systems.

Note that DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is useful for things like explode-ing a path that the system gave you.

From https://alanhogan.com/tips/php/directory-separator-not-necessary

Answer (score 0):

str_replace("**\\**","**/**",dirname(**FILE**)); works for me... (note double **"\\"** for scape  the 2nd **"\"**)